# File changes not reflecting immediately using nfs

Tags: linux, nfs

I have 4 servers- server A, B, C & D. I placed all the files on server D and mounted that directory to all servers i.e A, B & C. I am using NFS for mounting. Now the problem is when I am doing some changes in files on server D then it's not immediately reflected on server A, B & C. But when I do changes on A, B or C then it reflects immediately to all servers. 
NFS configurations are same for all servers.
I want immediate reflection of files from server D to all servers. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: How exactly do you test for an "immediate reflection"? And how do you change the files?

Comment: I deleted the file from server D and checked on server A and it was there and after few seconds it disappeared.

Comment: Are you using a graphical file manager or a cli utility?

Comment: I am not using any utility. I am continuously tracking this issue and current status is- we are facing using in nfs4 and not in nfs3. But why not working with nfs4 ?

Comment: my question was _how_ / _with what_ are you tracking? Oh, and maybe you run `cachefilesd`?